# How to make statistic of changes in column,that are string, grouped by other column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'RB': [2335] * 4 +  [3567] * 4 + [1245] * 4,
    'time': months[:4] * 3,
    'value': ['good day'] * 2 + ['may be'] * 2 + ['what'] * 4 + ['sure'] * 3 + ['no']
})
```

I would like to see how many RB made changes from good to maybe, from what to sure, sure to no, maybe to good etc.(all combinations)  Since there are a lot of combinations I would like to see if some are appearing more often. (Also maybe to good and good to maybe are two combination for example )

Comment: What's months? It's not in the question. Also, could you please add the expected output?

Comment: Data is a bit unclear, would you mind elaborating it with the expected result? Also, months seem to be another variable

Comment: Where do you get `months` from?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, assuming 'months' in an integer:

```
months = list(range(12))
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'RB': [2335] * 4 +  [3567] * 4 + [1245] * 4,
    'time': months[:4] * 3,
    'value': ['good day'] * 2 + ['may be'] * 2 + ['what'] * 4 + ['sure'] * 3 + ['no']
})

df = df.assign(next_val = df.groupby("RB").transform("shift", -1)["value"])
df["change"] = ((df.value != df.next_val) & df.next_val.notna()).map({False: 0, True:1})
df = df.groupby(["value", "next_val"]).sum()[["change"]]
df[df.change>0]
```

The result is:

```
                   change
value    next_val        
good day may be         1
sure     no             1
```